kotlin - How to display data from a foreground service to my UI?
I am trying to develop an Android app that collects location data from my device and sends it to an influxDB server even when the screen is off (and data should be sent live as I have clients observing my influxDb to track my device position).
I have an architecture with a ViewModel that controls a Repository that itself launches a Service to get the location updates.
It is constructed as this :
class LocationViewModel @Inject constructor(val context: Context, private val locationRepository: LocationRepository): ViewModel() {

    private val _locationUiState = MutableStateFlow(LocationUiState())
    val locationUiState: StateFlow<LocationUiState> = _locationUiState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            locationRepository.locationFlow.collect { location ->
                _locationUiState.update { currentState ->
                    currentState.copy(location = location)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    fun startLocationUpdates() {
        locationRepository.startLocationUpdates()

    }
}


My repository is defined as :
class LocationRepository @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext val context: Context) {
    // MutableSharedFlow to emit location updates
    private val _locationFlow = MutableStateFlow<Location?>(Location("")) // replay = 1 to hold the last emitted value
    val locationFlow : StateFlow<Location?> = _locationFlow

    // Function to update location in the repository
    fun updateLocation(location: Location) {
        _locationFlow.value = location
    }
    fun startLocationUpdates() {
        val serviceIntent = Intent(context, LocationService::class.java)
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, serviceIntent)
    }

And finally my service is defined the following way :
@AndroidEntryPoint
class LocationService(): Service() {

    @Inject lateinit var locationRepository: LocationRepository

    private lateinit var powerManager: PowerManager
    private lateinit var wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock

    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

    private val locationRequest = LocationRequest
        .Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, 1000)
        .setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(1000)
        .build()

    private var _locationData = MutableStateFlow<Location>(Location(""))
    val locationData: StateFlow<Location> = _locationData.asStateFlow()

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        powerManager = getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyApp::LocationWakeLock")
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        createNotificationChannel()
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

        wakeLock.acquire()

        startForeground(FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION, getNotification())

        val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                locationResult.lastLocation?.let { location ->
                        locationRepository.updateLocation(location)

                }
            }
        }
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
            locationCallback,
            Looper.getMainLooper())

        return START_STICKY
    }

The locationService works well and updates the locationFlow variable in my repository without any problem but I am struggling with passing the data from my Repository to my ViewModel.
I have tried many different approcaches with StateFlow or LiveData but none worked..
I am starting to think that this might be a problem with coroutines and the threads in which things happened but I am new to Kotlin and jetpack so I am not sure about this

You don't need to introduce the Repository layer for this use case.
From Martin Fowler
Mediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a collection-like interface for accessing domain objects.
You can try something like this.
@AndroidEntryPoint
class LocationService(): Service() {

    ...

    companion object {
        var onLocationResult: ((Location)-> Unit)? = null
    }
}

val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            locationResult.lastLocation?.let { location ->
                onLocationResult?.invoke(location)
            }
        }
}

Now, you can directly use this in your fragment/activity. (No need for ViewModel)
LocationService.onLocationResult = { location ->
    Log.d(TAG, "onLocationResult : Latitude- ${location.latitude}, Longitude- ${location.longitude}")
}

Do not forget this
In your Activity
override fun onDestroy() {
    LocationService.onLocationResult = null
    super.onDestroy()
}

In your Fragment
override fun onDestroyView() {
    LocationService.onLocationResult = null
    super.onDestroyView()
}


You can use localbroadcast intent as following
val broadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
        val action = intent.getStringExtra("action")
        Log.d("TAG", "onReceive: $action ")
        
    }
}


    getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(
        broadcastReceiver
    )

    getInstance(context).registerReceiver(
        broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter("custom-action-local-broadcast")
    )

// ------- sender ------ side //
val intent = Intent("custom-action-local-broadcast")
intent.putExtra("action", action)
getInstance(applicationContext).sendBroadcast(intent)

Not sure if this is helpful but here is a tutorial I wrote the same with Android using Java though: https://www.influxdata.com/blog/building-real-time-android-apps-influxdb-cloud and GitHub project https://github.com/InfluxCommunity/SensorLogger

The sensor management part / influxDB connection is okay on my side. The part I am really struggling with is the data flow from the foreground service to the UI and this tutorial doesn't address this

Answers should be able to stand on their own, links should only support the answer. For more see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259. Please add all relevant parts from the link to your answer.

The problem was actually that the LocationRepository instances in the LocationService and in the LocationViewModel were different (checked this using Log.d(className, "Hash code : $locationRepository.hashCode()) and therefore the LocationViewModel was not subscribing to the right repository.
To solve the issue I added @Singleton to my LocationRepository :
@Singleton
class LocationRepository @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext val context: Context)

